# Can't resolve './src'

Tags: npm, webpack, indexing, src

I'm learning react-redux app and now I'm trying to pass to th browser a "Hello World!" but when I start it with npm it appears an error and I don't really know how to fix it. Sorry I'm a bit noob in this coding world.
[npm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3V4a.png)

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZB4Vl.png)

[webpack.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtm9A.png)

Thanks in advance :)

---

**Edit:**

Below is my `index.js` code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/app';
ReactDOM.render( <App />, document.getElementById('app') );
```

Below is my `app.js` code:

```
import React from 'react'; export default () => ( <div>Hello world!</div> );

module.export = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename:'bungle.js'
  },
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /.js?$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      query: {
        presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
        plugins: ['transform-object-rest-spread']
      }
    }] 
  } 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the src folder in the root of the project or did you try to move it?

Although React officialy doesn't follow a specific folder structure and naming convention but its very common that developers normally place most of the logic inside src folder. Source folder can have a components folder where u store all folders, similarly inside the src folder you can have an images folder to store all the images , a css folder to store all the css and so on. You are right by default you get a src folder through creat react app. I guess the teacher you are following might create a src folder in the future or you can show me the code of your index file so i can tell u better

---

**Edit:** *(after OP provided `index.js` and `app.js`)*

That's strange. Although this shouldn't happen but what I'll recommend is to create another react project through create-react-app and try to run that to see if this is not some issue with React